# Where can I find an initial/default computer name per OS?

Tags: linux, windows, computer-name

After installing the OS you get an initial/default computer name, i.e. for some Windows computers is something like "WIN-SJ32FF4". Does it always start with "WIN-"? What would it be for Linux? Different releases?

Emphasis: I am looking for a list in order not to go through all possible os versions and check it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Most operating systems, including Windows, Linux, Mac support command `hostname`, which prints current machine name. You would need to open command prompt (`cmd` on Windows, `xterm` or `terminal` on other systems) and then type `hostname` to see it.

Speaking of defaults, there are basically none. Every OS, and every version of it may make different preferences about default computer name, so you cannot really predict it.

Also, default computer name maybe provided by DHCP server, and this is really not predictable.

Comment: This is exactly why I am looking for a list of these names - I know how to see the computer name but I don't want to go through all possible os versions ...

Comment: DHCP server may provide default computer name, so all bets are off

Comment: But I only have Windows computers in the network - I want all the names

Comment: All the names is a problem. Try installing windows a dozen times. Half the time on the same hardware, half the time on a second set of hardware. If you do it often enough you might be able to predict the 'random' part of the name. In other cases it is easier, e.g. slackware asks for a name during installation. If you provide none it will use 'darkstar'.

Comment: well, on my network, Linux computer may choose something else - simply because I have configured my DHCP server to offer certain names to the hosts by their mac address. Linux respects that offer, Windows may not. Long story short, you cannot predict it with 100% certainty

Comment: 1. I don't need the random part - just the base of the name
2. I don't care about options where the DHCP server chooses the name - just about stand alone computers.